# Merging the database records since last update for a Rails applicatoin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rubygems, migration

We are in the process of moving my Rails application from one cloud provider to another.

The migration plan is as below:

get the postgres dump of the db and move to the new cloud provider. We want to make the moving process as painless as possible for the customers. So we want to keep the existing application running until fully migrated to the new hosts and make sure everything working on the new instances to our satisfaction.

While we doing this, there is new data getting added (transaction data) to the current instance from the customers of our tenants. I would like to know if there is an easier way to pick just the recently added, we can even provide the ids of the models that we are interested.

Is there any gem out there that can create sql statements containing the model data so that we could just extract the new additions and run against the new cloud instance?

Comment: Do you have a lot of data? Would the dump and reload take a lot of time? If not, once you have tested that the new infrastructure is working, you could take a fresh dump and reload it before switching over? In any case, you would want to have at least a couple mins downtime to ensure 100% data consistency.

Comment: @RajeshKolappakam, Yes some of the tenants have huge set of data, and would like to avoid taking a dump again if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider an alternative migration plan like this:

1. Setup a warm replication from your old database to the new one, so that the new one is continuously updated with the data from the old one
2. Test the new infrastructure
3. Switch over the users to the new application
4. Turn off replication

Replication options with postgresql https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling

Comment: That sounds to be better and more professional approach. Thanks :)